# Does Abstract Algebra use classical logic?

Tags: logic

I didn't know there was something called classical logic. If there are mone than one logic, the book, "Abstract Algebra by Dummit, Foote" uses classical logic?

Comment: When people talk about logic in math, they mean formal logic, i.e., the study of logic itself. It is very technical. You will not need to worry about using a different type of logic with different textbooks.

Comment: You should know basic logic such as the contrapositive of an implication and proof by contradiction. You won't need much more than the basics for Dummit,Foote.

Comment: Whatever you do, *don't* read $\S0$ of Godement's *Algebra*! :)

Comment: Working mathematicians usually use classical logic unless they need to consider foundational issues. It could be worth mentioning that mathematics *not* based on classical logic is not well-studied.

Comment: Yes, usually. Without classical reasoning principles, one cannot prove statements like every commutative ring has a maximal ideal, and every vector space has a basis.

Comment: @xuq01: That has absolutely **nothing** to do with classical logic. ZF is a classical set theory that cannot prove what you are talking about. Arguably, AC is even **not** a classical reasoning principle in the presence of the power-set axiom of ZF.

Comment: @user682705: In short, classical first-order logic is the basis of modern mathematics, since ZFC set theory is a classical first-order theory, and modern mathematics can be expressed over ZFC. Normal mathematics does not need full ZFC, and ZC (no replacement and no foundation) will suffice, so you are likely to see only classical first-order reasoning and ZC axioms in any modern mathematics textbook.

Comment: Also note that any satisfactory foundational system must have classical logic for at least arithmetic and reasoning about finite strings, otherwise it would be unable to prove a lot of things of critical foundational interest. Non-classical logics can never be sufficient for such things. In fact, a lot of theorems about non-classical logics are proven in a meta-system that is based on classical logic...

Comment: @user21820 Maybe we are in a disagreement about word choice here. For many constructivists like me, all non-constructive reasoning principlea are simply referred to as "classical". Of course one can still have AC and its siblings in intuitionistic ZF, so strictly speaking yes it has nothing to do with classical logic. A better term would be "non-constructive

Comment: @xuq01: Sure. Yes, AC and LEM are non-constructive principles. I think we should not use the term "[classical](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical)" in a non-standard manner, since it would be confusing to many people. So thanks for clarifying what you meant. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that there are many different forms of logic, so `many logics'. I will mention a few that are sometimes used in mathematics.

In ordinary mathematics, one sometimes uses proof by contradiction.  You want to prove some proposition, so you assume that it is false and show that that leads to a contradiction. This corresponds to the 'Law of Excluded Middle' in classical logic. When LEM is used in set theory, it is fine with finite sets, but with infinite sets some mathematicians have queried if it should be assumed as a base Law for doing mathematics as one cannot check it. A similar objection is raised for the Axiom of Choice. Not allowing LEM leads to intuitionistic logic. (A neat intro to this sort of thing can be found in Steve Vickers book `Topology via Logic (Cambridge Tracts in Theoretical Computer Science)'. If you limit yourself to the introduction it is quite approachable, but don't worry about further on in the book.) These forms of logic may seem weird but can feed back into more standard mathematics in surprising ways (that I could not hope to describe here!).

Outside mathematics, there are many (e.g. modal) logics used in Artifical Intelligence that have neat mathematical interpretations.  If you set up things formally, logics end up being mathematical structures in their own right and so can be studied using methods from algebra, or topology, etc.

Comment: LEM has nothing to do with set theory...

Comment: @user21829 I beg to differ. You say `set theory' as if that was set in tablets of stone .... it is not! Which set theory do you mean?  There are lots of different set theories of varying strengths. Some of these do not allow the use of LEM. Look at the wikipedia pages on Constructive Set Theory. They may be a minority interest but they do exist. As Dan Christensen say in another answer, in textbooks, it is usual to use classical or standard logic, and thus classical or standard set theory, even naive set theory. Non-standard forms of set theory are often used in computer science and AI.

Comment: I know logic very well. You're wrong. LEM is a feature of the underlying logic, and has **nothing** to do with whatever set theory or type theory or whatever other foundational system is built on top. If you are only familiar with set theories, and not the other alternatives I mentioned, then that will explain your error.

Comment: @user 21820; I may not have chosen my words quite correctly and when I said 'to the 'Law of Excluded Middle' in set theory' I should have said 'the use of LEM in set theory'.  I am quite familiar with the categorical logics based on topos theoretic semantics, and hence with the extensive use of intuitionistic logic in particular, but had not wanted to give an unduly  complicated answer to a fairly simple query.

Comment: If it's just an issue of words, then I think you'll agree with my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It reads better than my original and is more accurate in the 'detail'.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In math textbooks (e.g. algebra, calculus and geometry), unless explicitly stated otherwise (in rare cases), classical (or standard) logic is assumed. It's just the ordinary, everyday rules of logic that include ability to remove double negations (logical NOT-operators) in statements, and the usual methods of proof (direct proof, proof by contradiction, proof by contrapositive).